# Unable to find declaration file for module 'react-axios'

Tags: typescript, axios, react-tsx

Here is an axios module for react, it called [react-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios).
I followed the document to install the modules. But when I import the module in my component, TS show me this error.

```sh
无法找到模块“react-axios”的声明文件。“D:/Project/Working/correlation-analysis-react/node_modules/react-axios/lib/index.js”隐式拥有 "any" 类型。
```

It mains that "Unable to find declaration file for module 'react-axios', the index.js implicitly has the "any" type".

I'm not sure if it's due to compatibility issues between this module and TypeScript. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? Or does anyone understand how this works?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your typescript environment was set up correctly there should be a declaration file named "react-app-env.d.ts"

If not, create one in the react app root directory.

Then add the line `declare module "react-axios";` in that file.